# How to tweak Full Page Cache?

Tags: full-page-cache

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
Amasty Full Page Cache
```

We got the following Email from a CFO of a large company:

"Your website is horrible!!  I tried to order from my ipad yesterday and kept getting kicked out.  Logged on to the computer this morning and it is almost as bad.  I can’t seem to get the order placed. When you are trying to place an order and you press continue, it will often kick you out.  Then you either have to start over or possibly it saves part of the info, but I always had to reenter the state for ship to and bill to.  It even kicked me out on the regular computer.  I gave up on the Ipad yesterday and then tried the computer this morning."

He was eventually able to place the order.

I wonder - are we having these issues because of the Full Page Cache and if so - what do I need to do to tweak it in such a way that this would not happen?